# Create a SharePoint abstract parent content type

Tags: inheritance, content-type

Is it possible to make a content type "abstract" in SharePoint 2010, i.e. users will only able to use the content types that inherit from the parent, and not create items/lists that use the base content type directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To a certain extent, declaring the content type as hidden may help you. More information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spcontenttype.hidden.aspx